# CORS error on sending API request via browser from a React pod to a Django pod

Tags: reactjs, django, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've created a basic Django-React web application, and am trying to deploy it through Kubernetes, on my local system. But, while sending an API request from the frontend to the backend, I'm getting the following message alert on the browser:

```
A server/network error occurred. Looks like CORS might be the problem. Sorry about this - we will get it fixed shortly.
```

I have set up ingress to basically deploy the pods, and to connect them. The alert message looks like the following:[image]

On clicking the 'OK', the console logs the following:
[image]

I have already tried setting the CORS headers in the axios request, as well as setting the Django settings as necessary. Here is the axios request:

```
const baseURL = API_SERVER + '/api/'; // API_SERVER resolves to http://127.0.0.1:8000

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem('access_token')
            ? 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
            : null,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        accept: 'application/json',
    }, 
});
```

And the Django `settings.py`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .
    .
    .
    'corsheaders',
    .
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    .
    .
    .
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://kubernetes.docker.internal",
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

`kubernetes.docker.internal` is the URL through which I'm accessing the application through Ingress, by running `minikube tunnel` on another terminal, and adding `127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal` to my `/etc/hosts` file. The manifest for ingress is as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "authorization, origin, content-type, accept"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          ################
          # URL ROUTING #
          ################
          - path: /admin
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: django-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 8000
          - path: /api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: django-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 8000
          ##########################
          # STATIC FOLDER ROUTING #
          ##########################
          - path: /static/admin/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: django-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 8000
          # ... bunch of other stuff
          ################
          # URL ROUTING #
          ################
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: react-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Also the manifests for the Django and React deployments are pretty standard, which just define deployments and services:

The manifest for the Django deployment

```
###########################
# Deployment
###########################
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: depl-django
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: django
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: django
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: django-container
          image: <dockerhub_username>/backend:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          command: ["bash", "-c", "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"]
          env:
            - name: DJANGO_ENV
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: app-config
                  key: DJANGO_ENV
            - name: SECRET_KEY
              valueFrom:......
            # ...other env variables....     

---
###########################
# Cluster IP Service
###########################
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: django-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: django
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
```

The manifest for React deployment:

```
###########################
# Deployment
###########################
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: depl-react
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: react
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: react
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: react-container
          image: <dockerhub_username>/frontend:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          command: ["sh", "-c", "serve -s build -l 3000 --no-clipboard"]       

---
###########################
# Cluster IP Service
###########################
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: react-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: react
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

I already tried a bunch of other solution from over the internet, but nothing seems to be working, including:

1. Setting the necessary `CORS` settings in the `settings.py` file in the main Django application.
2. Setting the necessary axios header: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',`
3. Setting metadata annotations in the ingress manifest

All of these can be seen in the files I have defined above. I expect for the frontend to send an API request to the server without any hassle. Also, the entire application is working locally, i.e., without any Kubernetes setup, the project is working perfectly fine on my local system.

Any help would be appreciated. Do let know if any other information is needed.

Comment: Prima facie the error does not looks like a CORS problem. Rather it is unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000.